# SQL query to get all records with a unique value of one column from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, unique

I am using SQL Server 2012 and Access.

I have two tables indexed on Well and Depth. The depths in each table for each well can be the same or different. I wish to create a single table with `Well, Depth` (one column each) and all other columns of the two tables, containing a list of all unique depths and the associated data at each depth.

The tables shown here are an example:

Table PT

| Well | Depth | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 100 | 10 |
| A1 | 150 | 15 |
| A1 | 200 | 20 |
| A1 | 250 | 25 |
| A1 | 300 | 30 |
| A2 | 69 | 121 |

Table SPIN

| Well | Depth | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 100 | 1000 |
| A1 | 120 | 1200 |
| A1 | 200 | 2000 |
| A1 | 300 | 3000 |
| A1 | 500 | 5000 |
| B2 | 103 | 250 |

The combined table, SPINPT, for well A1 should look like this:

| Well | Depth | Temperature | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 100 | 10 | 1000 |
| A1 | 120 |  | 1200 |
| A1 | 150 | 15 |  |
| A1 | 200 | 20 | 2000 |
| A1 | 250 | 25 |  |
| A1 | 300 | 30 | 3000 |
| A1 | 500 |  | 5000 |

I hoped this would be fairly easy, but I have searched the internet for solutions without success.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a full outer join between the two tables:

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(p.Well, s.Well) AS Well,
    COALESCE(p.Depth, s.Depth) AS Depth,
    p.Temperature,
    s.Frequency
FROM PT p
FULL OUTER JOIN SPIN s
    ON s.Well = p.Well AND
       s.Depth = p.Depth
ORDER BY
    Well,
    Depth;
```

### Demo

On MS Access, which does not directly support full outer joins, we can try simulating using a union of a left and right join between the two tables.

```sql
SELECT p.Well, p.Depth, p.Temperature, s.Frequency
FROM PT p
LEFT JOIN SPIN s ON s.Well = p.Well AND s.Depth = p.Depth
UNION ALL
SELECT s.Well, s.Depth, p.Temperature, s.Frequency
FROM PT p
RIGHT JOIN SPIN s ON s.Well = p.Well AND s.Depth = p.Depth
WHERE s.Well IS NULL
ORDER BY Well, Depth;
```

Comment: I have given you an option which might work on MS Access.

Comment: I have checked your code in Access, and it does not work correctly.  However the following code gives the correct results.SELECT p.Well, p.Depth, p.Temperature, s.Frequency
FROM PT p
LEFT JOIN SPIN s ON s.Well = p.Well AND s.Depth = p.Depth
UNION
SELECT s.Well, s.Depth, p.Temperature, s.Frequency
FROM PT p
RIGHT JOIN SPIN s ON s.Well = p.Well AND s.Depth = p.Depth
ORDER BY Well, Depth;

Comment: I'm not certain that your version is logically correct though.  The union (rather than union all) may be removing duplicates which you want to keep.

Comment: I don't wish to keep any duplicates.  The tables are indexed on Depth and the results of the query will go into another table indexed on Depth, so keeping duplicates of Depth is not allowed.  I have checked my version on the tables in the original question and the results are precisely what I require.  I will check on the actual tables of data before I incorporate this in the code.  Thanks for all your help.